# How do I turn off Default header styles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to migrate some code from Python 2.7 to 3.6

I noticed that some (not all) of my excel formatting doesn't work when running my code using a Python 3.6 virtualenv.

Specifically, this format is acting strangely:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True, 
    'font_color': 'white',
    'bg_color':'#004C99',
    'align':'center','valign':'vcenter',
    'text_wrap':'True','border':1
    })

worksheet.set_row(0,30,format1)
```

When ran in Python 2.7, the output looks like this:

[image]

When ran in Python 3.6 using a virtualenv, the output look like this:

[image]

It looks like what's causing this is Pandas 0.24 header default styles. My previous line to set the default style to none are as follows:

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this same thing in Pandas 0.24

What do you guys think?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code sample to reproduce your error ?
It s not clear what library you use to interact with excel sheets. Is it openpyxl or another one ??!